# how can I remove an average from each number and get average from certain region

Tags: r

I have a data like this

```
df<- structure(list(X1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), X2 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L), .Label = c("B02", "B03", "B04", 
"B05", "B06", "B07", "C02", "C03", "C04", "C05", "C06", "C07", 
"D02", "D03", "D04", "D05", "D06", "D07", "G02", "G03", "G04", 
"G05", "G06", "G07"), class = "factor"), X3 = c(0.005648642, 
0.005876389, 0.00592532, 0.006244456, 0.005987075, 0.006075874, 
0.006198667, 0.006003758, 0.006041885, 0.006186987, 0.006041323, 
0.006071594, 0.005902391, 0.005976096, 0.00593805, 0.005866524, 
0.0059831, 0.005902586, 0.005914309, 0.005887304, 0.006054509, 
0.005931266, 0.005936195, 0.005895191, 0.005840959, 0.005849247, 
0.005808851, 0.005833586, 0.005825153, 0.00584873, 0.005983976, 
0.00598669, 0.006011548, 0.005997747, 0.005851022, 0.005919044, 
0.005854566, 0.0058226, 0.00578052, 0.005784874, 0.005933198, 
0.005996407, 0.005898848, 0.00595775, 0.005918857, 0.005882898, 
0.005877808, 0.005803604, 0.006235161, 0.005808725)), .Names = c("X1", 
"X2", "X3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -50L))
```

I am trying to get the average of several numbers and then minus it from every single number in that data and then get average of specific numbers

Here is what I did

I first try to get the average of "G05", "G06", "G07" for each set (X1) 
Then I minus it from each value

```
df2 <- df1 %>%
  filter(X2 %in% paste0(paste0("G0", 5:7)) %>%
  group_by(X1) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(-X2), funs(mean(.)))
```

which should give me two numbers for group 1 and group 2( based on X1)

mean(c(0.005931266,0.005936195,0.005895191))
[1] 0.005920884

mean(c(0.005803604,0.006235161,0.005808725))
[1] 0.005949163

Then I want to remove this value from each number in group 1 and group 2 based on their group

for example 
0.005648642- 0.005920884 
.
.
.
.
0.005840959- 0.005949163

**In simple words**

1- We get the mean of G05 , G06 and G07 for two groups where X1 is 1 or 2

for example

```
mean(c(0.005931266,0.005936195,0.005895191)) [1] 0.005920884

mean(c(0.005803604,0.006235161,0.005808725)) [1] 0.005949163
```

2- We remove these mean values from every single number 
for example

```
0.005648642- 0.005920884 
.
.
.
.
0.005840959- 0.005949163
```

3- After this correction Then I want to take avererge of specific rows which will be for both groups

For example

B02 and B03 for both group

```
average(c(0.005648642- 0.005920884,0.005876389- 0.005920884))
```

and

```
average(c(0.005808851- 0.005949163,0.005833586 - 0.005949163))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I this what you're after?

1. Steps 1 and 2:

   Split on `X1` (i.e. group by `X1`) and center the values in `X3` based on the mean across `G05`, `G06`, `G07`:

   ```
   lst <- lapply(split(df, df$X1), function(w) {
       w.G0567 <- subset(w, grepl("G0[567]", w$X2));
       print(mean(w.G0567$X3));
       w$X3 <- w$X3 - mean(w.G0567$X3);
       return(w);
   })
   #[1] 0.005920884
   #[1] 0.005949163
   lst;
   #$`1`
   #   X1  X2           X3
   #1   1 B02 -0.000272242
   #2   1 B03 -0.000044495
   #3   1 B04  0.000004436
   #4   1 B05  0.000323572
   #5   1 B06  0.000066191
   #6   1 B07  0.000154990
   #7   1 C02  0.000277783
   #8   1 C03  0.000082874
   #9   1 C04  0.000121001
   #10  1 C05  0.000266103
   #11  1 C06  0.000120439
   #12  1 C07  0.000150710
   #13  1 D02 -0.000018493
   #14  1 D03  0.000055212
   #15  1 D04  0.000017166
   #16  1 D05 -0.000054360
   #17  1 D06  0.000062216
   #18  1 D07 -0.000018298
   #19  1 G02 -0.000006575
   #20  1 G03 -0.000033580
   #21  1 G04  0.000133625
   #22  1 G05  0.000010382
   #23  1 G06  0.000015311
   #24  1 G07 -0.000025693
   #
   #$`2`
   #   X1  X2            X3
   #25  2 C02 -1.082043e-04
   #26  2 C03 -9.991633e-05
   #27  2 B02 -1.403123e-04
   #28  2 B03 -1.155773e-04
   #29  2 B04 -1.240103e-04
   #30  2 B05 -1.004333e-04
   #31  2 B06  3.481267e-05
   #32  2 B07  3.752667e-05
   #33  2 C02  6.238467e-05
   #34  2 C03  4.858367e-05
   #35  2 C04 -9.814133e-05
   #36  2 C05 -3.011933e-05
   #37  2 C06 -9.459733e-05
   #38  2 C07 -1.265633e-04
   #39  2 D02 -1.686433e-04
   #40  2 D03 -1.642893e-04
   #41  2 D04 -1.596533e-05
   #42  2 D05  4.724367e-05
   #43  2 D06 -5.031533e-05
   #44  2 D07  8.586667e-06
   #45  2 G02 -3.030633e-05
   #46  2 G03 -6.626533e-05
   #47  2 G04 -7.135533e-05
   #48  2 G05 -1.455593e-04
   #49  2 G06  2.859977e-04
   #50  2 G07 -1.404383e-04
   ```
2. Step 3

   For every group, average centred `X3` values for `B02` and `B03`.

   ```
   lapply(lst, function(w) mean(subset(w, X2 %in% c("B03", "B03"))$X3))
   #$`1`
   #[1] -4.4495e-05
   #
   #$`2`
   #[1] -0.0001155773
   ```

Comment: no this is not what I meant, I want to get the average of G05 to G07 for group1 and group2 . then remove its avreage from each value of group1 or group 2

Comment: @nik I *do* calculate the means for `X1=1` and `X1=2`, and center values for each `X1` accordingly (or as you call it "remove its average from each value of group1 or group2").

Comment: And you didn't answer my questions. What "specific numbers" are you referring to? Why do you suddenly talk about `B02` and `B03`? Do you mean `G02` and `G03`?

Comment: no no, please read my text above carefuly. we have only two values  0.005920884 and 0.005949163.  The first one is for those that X1 is 1 and the second one is for those that their X1 is 2. does it make sense?

Comment: @nik Yes I'm with you. We have two means, one for each group. I subtract that from the `X3` values for every group. Take a look at my code, specifically the line `w$X3 <- w$X3 - mean(w$X3)`! If you change my code, and include a `print(mean(w$X3))` you will see the same two numbers.

Comment: look I get the average of G05 to G07 in X1 with 1. then X1 with 2 . I will have two values 0.005920884 and 0.005949163. Then I start using these values to correct for them. we look at the first data it does not matter which number, just NUMBER-0.005920884 or NUMBER -0.005949163 for X1 of 1 and X1 of 2 , respectively

Comment: @nik So for every group, you want to subtract the mean based *only* on values where `X2=G05,G06,G07`? That's not very clear from your OP where you talk about G06, G07, G08, and then later about B02, B03. You also talk about "dividing the average" in your OP. So which one is it? Division or subtraction? I'm sorry but this is really not very clear.

Comment: I added more information in my question. please look above

Comment: @nik Please take some time to **carefully** and **thoroughly** edit your question. It's **full of inconsistencies**. First you talk about averaging across G06, G07, G08, then later it becomes G05, G06, G07. In the first part you want to "divide it from each value", then later you subtract the means. You still have not answered any of my questions towards the end of my post.

Comment: done, thanks for your comment. Now it is what you asked

Comment: @nik Ok. I think I understand. I've edited my answer. Please take a look.

Comment: unfortunately it does not work when i use another data. can you make it more general that accept any col name ?

Comment: @nik You need to be more specific than *"it does not work"*. *What* did not work? *How* did it not work? My solution is based on the sample data you provide. It's difficult for me to guess what a "more general" solution would have to look like without representative sample data.